# Rectangular image

Tags: android, android-imageview

If I have an imageview on my app, here's the code

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView5"
    android:layout_width="300px"
    android:layout_height="90px"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
```

And I want to put the company logo in that image view (the logo is 300px by 90px)

I know I have to import that in as a drawable (right click on drawable -> new image asset), but it is only giving me options for icons that are square, which won't work for this logo.

How do I go about putting a rectangular image into my app.

Comment: can you explain more clearly.

Comment: can you add your logo and update your question with more detail

Comment: @AkshayKatariya I don't see how having the logo would make a difference. I have described it as a 300px by 90px image. The question is simple, how do I import a rectangular image to my app, it is only giving me options for square icons.

Comment: add image in folder res/drawable-nodpi/myimage.png
later add in xml in ImageView line:
  android:src="@drawable/myimage"
link: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Bitmap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to import it with the IDE, you can just paste your logo "your_logo.png" on the drawable folder, then you can acces it by adding :

```
android:src="@drawable/your_logo"
```

to your ImageView

Comment: Thanks this works, will mark as answer in 7 minutes.